# The snackbar I created in Flutter appears above the navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

```
WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          DateTime now = DateTime.now();

          if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
              now.difference(currentBackPressTime!) >
                  const Duration(seconds: 2)) {
            currentBackPressTime = now;

            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                
                backgroundColor: red,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                elevation: 6.0,
                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40,0,40,0),
                content: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Press back button again to exit',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: buttonstyle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );

            return false;
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: child);
```

Where I call the Snackbar widget.

```
SnackbarWidget(
  child: Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
              items: const [...],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndex),
      )
      
      ),
);
```

I have a snackbar widget in Flutter that I say will close the app once the user hits the back button twice. And the navigation bar I created. But as seen in the image, this snackbar appears above the navigation bar and I cannot push the snackbar into the navigation bar in any way.

[Snackbar and navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilvCU.png)